# Executing Shell command on current line without selection

Tags: bash, emacs

I am using emacs to edit bash code (file ending in .sh).
In many IDE's like R-studio, I can do simply do ctrl-enter and
the current line is executed in the shell (in the R-studio case it is executed in R).

Is there a way for me to set ctrl-enter in the .sh mode that will execute the current line in xterm (within emacs)?

Thanks

Comment: did you try `C-c C-n`, it is bound to `sh-send-line-or-region` by default

Comment: Cool. I did not know this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

… try `C-c C-n`, it is bound to `sh-send-line-or-region` by default
                    – jenesaisquoi